# How to compare integer arrays?

Tags: c, strcmp

I have four sensors (sen0-sen3) which return either `1` or `0` and I am making an array of values using `sprintf`. Then I am trying to compare them with `0000` or `1000` and so on.

My Problem is even if the value of `sen_array` is `1000`, it never goes into the `else if` condition (straight to `else` condition).

```
char sen_array[4];

sprintf(sen_array,"%d%d%d%d",sen0,sen1,sen2,sen3);
if(strcmp("0000",sen_array)==0)
{
    motor_pwm((156*(0.20).),(156*(0.20)));
}
else if(strcmp("1000",sen_array)==0)
{
    motor_pwm((156*(0.40)),(156*(0.40)));
}
else
{
    motor_pwm((156*(0.80)),(156*(0.80)));
}
```

Comment: In `sprintf(sen_array,"%d%d%d%d%d",sen0,sen1,sen2,sen3);` you have 5 `%d` format specifiers and only 4 variables.

Comment: please show how you declare `sen_array`.

Comment: `sprintf()`? `strcmp`? Is this really C++? Also are sen[0-3] always `bool`?

Comment: 1. If sen0-3 will be greater than 9 you will have memory over run

Comment: 2. use int sen_array[4]; and memcmp (sen_array, _OOOO) or memcpy (sen_array, _1000)

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is an artifact of memory corruption. The problem is that you've declared `sen_array` to be a `char[4]`, which doesn't leave room for a terminating null. Change `sen_array` to:

```
char sen_array[5];
```

Answer (score 2):

Not using STL, I think the best way to compare integer arrays is using the `memcmp` function which compares blocks of memory.

```
int sen_array1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 } ;
int sen_array2[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 } ;
if(memcmp(sen_array1, sen_array2, sizeof(int)*4) == 0) { /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sen_array should be at least 5 chars long - to make room for a 0-terminator.

```
char sen_array[4];
sprintf(sen_array, "%d%d%d%d", 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

The above writes '1' '2' '3' '4' '\0' to sen_array - overflowing it and perhaps affecting a nearby variable

Use `char sen_array[5];`

A perhaps better solution would be to work with an integer:

```
int sa = sen0 * 1000 + sen1 * 100 + sen2 * 10 + sen3;

if (sa == 1000) {
  ...
} else if (sa == 1001) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: @Khali: sen_array needs to be 5 chars long, at least.

Comment: @Khali: sprintf 0-terminates - it'll write your four integers followed by a '\0' character - this overflows your current sen_array and can make anything happen.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: In the OP it's stated that the sen variables have value 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think sen_array should be atleast 5 chars long and unless you are using the sen_array for something else, A better and faster way is to do

```
int res = 1000*sen0+100*sen1+10*sen2+sen3;
```

And use this to compare.